# Attaching a google drive file in mail using code (preferably Python)

Tags: python, gmail-api, smtplib

I need to attach **the same file** in multiple emails using code (currently I am using python).

Iterating over this process for each mail ends up **uploading** the same file multiple times which further leads to exceeding the gmail's daily upload limits .
 To get around this , I thought of using a google drive file as the attachment , which ( I think ) should not add to gmail's *uploaded* *data* *size* (Do tell me if I am wrong).

Does anyone know how to attach a google drive file in a mail using code , i.e. the MIME type and how to refer to the google drive file ?.
I use the following code to attach a 'normal' file .

```
import smtplib
import email
msg = MIMEMultipart()
# 
#add the to , from , subject ,text params of 'msg' 
#
for attach in attachments:
    part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
    part.set_payload(open(attach, 'rb').read())
    encoders.encode_base64(part)
    part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="%s"' % os.path.basename(attach))
    msg.attach(part)
mailServer = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", <port_number>)
mailServer.sendmail(gmail_user, to + cc + bcc, msg.as_string())
```

Comment: Isn't that done automatically?

Comment: which part ?
Just to make the objective clear :
All I want is :
    1. not to breach the daily gmail upload limit .
    2. the file should show as an attachment (with the attachment icon in the mail ) .
Issue:


But attaching a google drive file , in such a way that it doesn't add to the upload size , beats me .
Downloading a google drive file , and then uploading it is the same as uploading a 'normal' file .

Comment: can't you just put the link to the file?

Comment: But that is not what I want  :P . I want the file to show up as an attachment , and at the same time not count as an upload (as it is a google drive file) . Putting a link will not display the file as an attachment (with the attachment icon in the mail ) .

Comment: Are you positive you can 'attach' a file without uploading it ? I mean you want to attach a file which is practically online and not link to it nor upload it, how does that make sense ?

Comment: OK , I get the flaw in my logic here . So , I guess ,it would be prudent to say one simply cannot 'attach' a google-drive file without it counting as an upload on the gmail account .